# How to work with AWS cloud controller manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to expose my applications running in my kubernetes cluster through AWS load balancer.
 I followed the document https://cloudyuga.guru/blog/cloud-controller-manager   and got till the point where i added `--cloud-provider=external`  in *kubeadm.conf* file. 
But this document is based on Digitial Ocean cloud and i'm working on AWS, i'm confused if i have to run any deployment.yaml file to get the pods running which are in pending status if so please provide me the link, i'm stuck at this point.

```
NAME                                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-66bff467f8-dlx76                                0/1     Pending   0          3m32s
coredns-66bff467f8-svb6z                                0/1     Pending   0          3m32s
etcd-ip-172-31-74-144.ec2.internal                      1/1     Running   0          3m38s
kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-74-144.ec2.internal            1/1     Running   0          3m38s
kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-74-144.ec2.internal   1/1     Running   0          3m37s
kube-proxy-rh8g4                                        1/1     Running   0          3m32s
kube-proxy-vsvlt                                        1/1     Running   0          3m28s
kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-74-144.ec2.internal            1/1     Running   0          3m37s
```

Answer (score 1):

The `coredns` pods are `pending` because you have not installed a Pod Network add-on yet. From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) you can choose any supported Pod Network add-on. For example to use calico

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml
```

After the Pod Network add-on is installed the `coredns` pods should come up.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the response @Arghya Sadhu, it helped me a lot :), i wonder how i missed that!